# Less than operator in typescript gives wrong result

Tags: typescript, numbers

I have troubles with numeric comparison on typescript.

I have the following function:

```
function fun(a: number, b: number) {
    console.log(a+"<"+b+": " + (a < b))
    console.log(a+"<"+b+": " + (parseInt(a.toString()) < parseInt(b.toString())))
    if (a < b)
        return something
    return something else
}
```

If i test a=60 and b=100 the first line answers `60<100: false`, while the second says correctly `60<100: true`.
I was thinking that 100 if before 60 as text, but I'm passing `number` as parameters: what's wrong?

Comment: My guess is that you’re not actually sending `number` parameters to the function.  Where is the code that calls the function?  That’s where your problem is

Comment: You're right: the json file where i get the values from contains text values... Thanks for the hint!

Comment: It's strange, but sometimes you have to ask for dummy questions to see the light :-(